# Mouse click through top image

Tags: javascript, createjs, mouseclick-event

I created two shapes with image as source using createjs(img1 and img2 at same position but z index is different). one image is on top of another image i.e. img2 on img1 in canvas. and image below has click event i.e. img1 has click event which work fine. but when i enable img2(not having any click event) on img1 than mouse click event work through top image. if add click event to img2 than it work properly. is that compulsory to add click event to each image to avoid click through images.

CODE:

```
[function test(){
        var btnContainer=new createjs.Container();
        btnContainer.mouseChildren=true;

        var shape = new createjs.Shape();        
        shape.graphics.clear().beginBitmapFill(loader.getResult("play-btn")).drawRect(0,0,291,98);//"no-repeat"
        shape.x=shape.y=200;
        shape.mouseEnabled =true;
        shape.addEventListener("click", playClick);


        var shape1 = new createjs.Shape();        
        shape1.graphics.clear().beginBitmapFill(loader.getResult("play-btn")).drawRect(0,0,291,98);//"no-repeat"
        shape1.x=shape1.y=250;
        shape1.mouseEnabled =true;
        shape1.addEventListener("click", playClickShape1);



        btnContainer.addChild(shape,shape1);


        gameStage.AddChildWidget(btnContainer);

    }


    function playClick(event)
    {
        console.log("\[playClick\] Start");
        ReadXMLFile();
    }
    function playClickShape1(event)
    {
        console.log("\[playClickShape1\] Start");
    }
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Sebastian is correct for DOM elements (with the CSS solution).

If both images are bitmaps in Canvas (via EaselJS), then a similar limitation exists. Anything with a "click" event will block clicks on elements below. Unlike HTML though, if there is no mouse event on an element, it will not block mouse events (basically it has `pointer-events:none` by default.

If you want to determine if a click happened on any element (regardless of layering), you could listen for clicks on the stage, and use `getObjectsUnderPoint()` to determine what was clicked, and you could check if either (or both) were clicked that way.

```
stage.on("stagemouseup", function(event) {
    var objs = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(event.stageX, event.stageY);
    for (var i=0, l=objs.length; i<l; i++) {
      var obj = objs[i];
      if (obj == firstElement || obj == secondElement) { doSomething(); break; }
    }
);
```

Docs:
https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#method_getObjectsUnderPoint

Answer (score 1):

If some image is overlaying other content which as click handler, it won't be registered as the top one will be blocking clicks. It won't propagate clicks to the bottom of the site. Try adding `pointer-events:none` css rule to the top image that you don't want registering click events, and the one on the bottom should be clickable.